# Hello everybody, i am having a trouble in laravel spatie permission package and the error is "in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, int given "

Tags: laravel

I am using Spatie package for laravel role and permission. I had extend default permission table and the code looks like this,

```
protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'create', 'read', 'update', 'delete'
    ];
```

I had also extend role and permission pivot table "role_has_permissions" and the relation looks like this,

Permission.php

```
public function roles(): BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(
            config('permission.models.role'),
            config('permission.table_names.role_has_permissions'),
            PermissionRegistrar::$pivotPermission,
            PermissionRegistrar::$pivotRole
        )->withPivot('create', 'read', 'update', 'delete');;
    }
```

Role.php

```
public function permissions(): BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(
            config('permission.models.permission'),
            config('permission.table_names.role_has_permissions'),
            PermissionRegistrar::$pivotRole,
            PermissionRegistrar::$pivotPermission
        )->withPivot('create', 'read', 'update', 'delete');;
    }
```

and the migrations file looks like this,

```
Schema::create($tableNames['role_has_permissions'], function (Blueprint $table) use ($tableNames) {
            $table->unsignedBigInteger(PermissionRegistrar::$pivotPermission);
            $table->unsignedBigInteger(PermissionRegistrar::$pivotRole);
            $table->boolean('create');
            $table->boolean('read');
            $table->boolean('update');
            $table->boolean('delete');
            $table->foreign(PermissionRegistrar::$pivotPermission)
                ->references('id')
                ->on($tableNames['permissions'])
                ->onDelete('cascade');

            $table->foreign(PermissionRegistrar::$pivotRole)
                ->references('id')
                ->on($tableNames['roles'])
                ->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->primary([PermissionRegistrar::$pivotPermission, PermissionRegistrar::$pivotRole], 'role_has_permissions_permission_id_role_id_primary');
        });

        app('cache')
            ->store(config('permission.cache.store') != 'default' ? config('permission.cache.store') : null)
            ->forget(config('permission.cache.key'));
    }
```

First of all, i create permission with all crud. After this i create role with permission. Creating is not problem but while i try to edit role with permission, i could not get the data from pivot table. Here is my attampt,

```
$role = Role::find($id);
    foreach ($role->permissions as $permission) {
        $rolePermission = $permission->pivot;
    }
$permissions = Permission::all();
$create = $rolePermission->pluck('create', 'create')->toArray();
return view('backend.rolepermission.edit', compact('role', 'permissions', 'create'));
```

when i try to use in_array method in blade file, the error comes.
The blade file looks like this,

```
<td>
                                        <div>
                                            <input type="hidden" name="create[{{$id}}]" value="0">
                                            <input class="form-check-input" name="create[{{$id}}]" type="checkbox" value="1" aria-label="..." @if(in_array(1,$create)) checked @endif>
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
```

and the value of create column also change 1 to 0 and array to integer.
Please share me some solutions how should i solve this problem. Thanks!

Comment: Please share more details, like the code involved and your attempts to resolve the problem

Comment: I had added code, please check , thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you want to check if user has a role. Like a admin etc. You can use the Spatie permission package methods like:

`$user->hasRole([1]); *(// if admin has the id 1)*`.

Also you can check native with the laravel pluck function. User can have multiple roles. It means that you $user->role is a collection.

```php
    foreach($user->roles()->pluck('name') as $role_name){
      if ($role_name === 'admin') {
         ...
      }
    }
```

Or with `in_array()`

```php
    in_array('admin', $user->roles);
```

Comment: Thanks, please review my question, i had added more detail. Thanks!